# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error Python " SQL Lite

Tags: python, sqlite, insert, postgresqlstudio

I have a small problem with a piece of code, I copied it from a web, but I have the following error:

sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error

The code is the following:

```
# Import required modules
import csv
import sqlite3
 
 

# Connecting to the geeks database
connection = sqlite3.connect('isaDBCommune.db')
 
# Creating a cursor object to execute
# SQL queries on a database table
cursor = connection.cursor()
 
# Table Definition
create_table = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS isaCommune(
                id_codedep_codecommune INTEGER NOT NULL,
                nom_commune TEXT NOT NULL,
                code_postal INTEGER NOT NULL,
                code_commune INTEGER NOT NULL,
                code_departement INTEGER NOT NULL,
                nom_departement TEXT NOT NULL,
                code_region INTEGER NOT NULL
                )'''

# Creating the table into our
# database
cursor.execute(create_table)
 
# Opening the person-records.csv file
file = open('commune.csv')
 
# Reading the contents of the
# person-records.csv file
contents = csv.reader(file)

# SQL query to insert data into the
# person table
 insert_records = "INSERT INTO isaCommune  (id_codedep_codecommune, nom_commune, code_postal, code_commune, code_departement, nom_departement, code_region) VALUES ('id_codedep_codecommune', 'nom_commune', 'code_postal', 'code_commune', 'code_departement', 'nom_departement', 'code_region')"

 
# Importing the contents of the file
# into our person table
cursor.executemany (insert_records, contents)
 
# SQL query to retrieve all data from
# the person table To verify that the
# data of the csv file has been successfully
# inserted into the table
select_all = "SELECT * FROM isaCommune"
rows = cursor.execute(select_all).fetchall()
```

What would be the solution? I have searched all over Stack Overflow and I can't find the solution

THX

Any solution ? Or explanation to this error that for me is hidden?

New error with correction ...

sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 1 supplied.

Comment: it should be  `INSERT INTO isaCommune ([list of column names]) VALUES  ([list of values])`  you need to fill the list of column names and list of values.

Comment: Error sqlite3.OperationalError: table isaCommune has no column named 'id_codedep_codecommune', 'nom_commune', 'code_postal', 'code_commune', 'code_departement', 'nom_departement', 'code_region'


insert_records = "INSERT INTO isaCommune (['id_codedep_codecommune', 'nom_commune', 'code_postal', 'code_commune', 'code_departement', 'nom_departement', 'code_region']) VALUES (['id_codedep_codecommune', 'nom_commune', 'code_postal', 'code_commune', 'code_departement', 'nom_departement', 'code_region'])"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will be your answer:-

```
import csv
import sqlite3
 
connection = sqlite3.connect('isaDBCommune.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()
create_table = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS isaCommune(
                id_codedep_codecommune TEXT NOT NULL,
                nom_commune TEXT NOT NULL,
                code_postal TEXT NOT NULL,
                code_commune TEXT NOT NULL,
                code_departement TEXT NOT NULL,
                nom_departement TEXT NOT NULL,
                code_region TEXT NOT NULL
                )'''
cursor.execute(create_table)
file = open('commune.csv')
contents = csv.reader(file)
for l in contents:
    insert_records = """INSERT INTO isaCommune ('id_codedep_codecommune', 'nom_commune', 'code_postal','code_commune','code_departement','nom_departement','code_region')
    VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)""" 
    a = (l[0],l[1],l[2],l[3],l[4],l[5],l[6],)
    cursor.execute(insert_records, a)
select_all = "SELECT * FROM isaCommune"
rows = cursor.execute(select_all).fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

Hope it will work now...

Comment: Nop ....  a = (l[0],l[1],l[2],l[3],l[4],l[5],l[6],)
IndexError: list index out of range

How can I send you the csv file???

Comment: If you have 7 columns in your csv file then it should work

Comment: How many fields are there in your csv file???

Comment: 7 fields separate comma

Comment: '1001,LABERGEMENCLEMENCIAT,1400,1,1,Ain,84' Like this??

Comment: Perfect, your code has worked perfectly, excellent. I put problem solved!!!

Answer (score -1):

You need to replace the '?' by the value you want to insert in the corresponding column depending on its type INTEGER, TEXT etc..

For example:

```
insert_records = "INSERT INTO isaCommune  VALUES(1, 'test', 1, 1, 1, 'test', 1)  ('id_codedep_codecommune', 'nom_commune', 'code_postal', 'code_commune', 'code_departement', 'nom_departement', 'code_region')"
```

Comment: I am reading from a csv, maybe an error there?

id_codedep_codecommune;nom_commune;code_postal;code_commune;code_departement;nom_departement;code_region
1001;L ABERGEMENT CLEMENCIAT;1400;1;1;Ain;84

Comment: insert_records = "INSERT INTO isaCommune VALUES (id_codedep_codecommune, 'nom_commune', code_postal, code_commune, code_departement, 'nom_departement', code_region) ('id_codedep_codecommune', 'nom_commune', 'code_postal', 'code_commune', 'code_departement', 'nom_departement', 'code_region') "
 

sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error